# Convert dataframe to tuple and then back into dataframe in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking to get a dataframe back from a list of tuples using the following:

```
tuples = tuple(df.itertuples(index=False))
#do some code, passing out df
ls = [(tup._fields, pd.Series(tup).to_frame()) for tup in tuples]
```

What I do to get the named tuple is tup._fields.

I would like to recreate the dataframe as it was, but I cannot do this pythonic-ly.

**How would I go about merging this list into one complete dataframe with the `tup._fields` as the column header?**

I have tried:

```
ls = [pd.Series(tup).loc[0] for tup in tuples]
df=pd.DataFrame({tup._fields: ls})
```

This assumes I only have a one row series in the variable `tup`, but this won't work for bigger dfs.

Comment: Found this in the documentation tup._fields, so amending the original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why are you extracting the `tup._fields` line? You can convert back with a list of `NamedTuple`.

Consider this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
       'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})

tuples = tuple(df.itertuples(index=False))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(tuples))

df2.head()

#>    one  two
#> 0  1.0  1.0
#> 1  2.0  2.0
#> 2  3.0  3.0
#> 3  NaN  4.0
```